# How to access an element having [ ] in id using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jsp file I am constructing a list of readonly input elements. An example of such element is as below:

```
<input type="text" 
       id="myElement[0]" 
       size="12" 
       maxlength="20" 
       readonly="readonly" 
       name="myElement[0]" 
       value="Some Value"

<input type="text" 
       id="myElement[1]" 
       size="12" 
       maxlength="20" 
       readonly="readonly" 
       name="myElement[1]" 
       value="Another Value"
```

I am now trying to access the value of first element by using below code:

```
value = $("#myElement[0]").val();
```

Unfortunately value comes out to be undefined. When I inspect `$("#myElement[0]")` this seems to be a non null object. But for some reason value comes out to be undefined.

Is there a different way of accessing this element.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see why you would name them that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enclose in single quotes to match exact using the attribute selector.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLpgE/)**

```
value = $("[id='myElement[0]']").val();
```

You can also escape the square bracket using `\\`

```
value = $("#myElement\\[0\\]").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

escape them using `\` - since `\` itself is a escape character, you need to use `\\`

```
value = $("#myElement\\[0\\]").val();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e2FFP/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the square brackets for selector syntax.

Then you need to escape the escape characters for JavaScript string literal syntax.

```
$("#myElement\\[0\\]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `[]`

```
 value = $("#myElement\\[0\\]").val();
```

From [**DOCs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \\.

*OR*

You can [**Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
value = $("[id='myElement[0]']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use escape:

```
$("#myElement\\[0\\]")
```

This works by escaping all CSS meta-characters listed on the [Selectors page of the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) with two backslashes.